# recognize virtual environment

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, vmware

in one of my last job interview I was asked a question , that till now i don’t even find a clue for how to solved it.

since it is very interesting question I thought maybe someone here will have an idea.

The question in quit simple:
"suggest a way to build application that will be able to recognize  if it running on virtual machine or not."
(VM not refer to something like CLR or JVM but to fully virtualization environment that you can build using VMware)

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't mean VMware? A Java app can only run inside JVM (same goes for C#/CLR).

Comment: I'm interested in the reason behind why you would want to detect that.

Comment: this was job interview question- so no reason given

Comment: Actually detecting virtualised environments can be really important when it comes to licensing software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Thwarting Virtual Machine
Detection](http://handlers.sans.org/tliston/ThwartingVMDetection_Liston_Skoudis.pdf), a presentation on how to do the reverse (stopping an application detecting that it is running on a VM in order to prevent malicious programs from changing their behaviour)

This presentation lists a number of different mechanisms that are typically used to detect a virtual machine environment:

- Look in the operating system (e.g. the registry, filesystem) for "tell-tale" signs that this is a VM (references to VMWare are a dead giveaway)
- Look at where critical memory structures (such as the [IDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table)) are placed in memory - typically this is placed higher in memory on virtual machines than it is physical machines.
- Look for VM-specific virtual hardware (such as network adapters or USB controllers)
- Look for anomalies in the way that the clock is synchronised with the host machine.
- Look for VM-specific processor capabilities - some virtual machines introduce additional machine language instructions beyond the standard x86 instruction set (for things like guest-to-host communication)

Ultimately however there is no 100% reliable way to detect if you are running on a virtual machine - if the goal is to provide a completely undetectable environment then each of these mechanisms can be "fixed" so that the VM is completely undetectable.

Comment: I've also seen instances where data is taken directly from the processor caches, branch predictions and other hard-to-virtualize info in order to detect anomalies indicating virtualization. Basically, virtualization is an arms race between those virtualizing and those detecting.